# From XML url to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xml, xml-parsing

I'm new to Python and I'm having some trouble importing a simple XML file from the web and converting it into a pandas DF:
https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/euro_reference_exchange_rates/html/cny.xml

I tried several methods, including using BS4, but I didn't get to make them work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
socket = requests.get('https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/euro_reference_exchange_rates/html/cny.xml')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(socket.content, ['lxml', 'xml'])

all_obs = soup.find_all('Obs')

l = []
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['TIME_PERIOD','OBS_VALUE'])
pos= 0
for obs in all_obs:
    l.append(obs.find('TIME_PERIOD').text)
    l.append(obs.find('OBS_VALUE').text)
    


    df.loc[pos] = l
    l = []
    pos+=1
    
print(df)
```

Could someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aiii!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get('https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/euro_reference_exchange_rates/html/cny.xml')

bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, ['xml'])

obs = bs.find_all("Obs")
#<Obs OBS_CONF="F" OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="10.7255" TIME_PERIOD="2005-04-01"/>

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['TIME_PERIOD','OBS_VALUE'])

for node in obs:
    df = df.append({'TIME_PERIOD': node.get("TIME_PERIOD"), 'OBS_VALUE': node.get("OBS_VALUE")}, ignore_index=True)
    
df.head()
```